# OnBackPressed en NavigationView

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy utilizando la plantilla de Android Studio y añade a la clase principal este método:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

¿Alguien sabe para que sirve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando realizas un back press (pulsar el botón `Atrás` de dispositivo), si el [NavigationView](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) esta abierto, lo cierra. Si no esta abierto, ejecuta `onBackPressed()` que regularmente cierra la Actividad.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        //esta abierto el NavigationView???
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            //Cierra el NavigationView.
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else { //No esta abierto.
            //ejecuta onBackPressed().
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```